# Whats the deal with a performance counter Parent?

Tags: c#, winapi

When I create performance counters in Windows Vista, I see that there is a "parent" column in the performance monitor listview that lists the counters.

What is parent?  I haven't seen a way to set it using managed code.  Is it only available if I use the Winapi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The syntax of a counter path is:
>
> ```
> \\Computer\PerfObject(ParentInstance/ObjectInstance#InstanceIndex)\Counter
> ```
>
> The Computer element specifies the
>   name or IP address of the computer
>   from which you want to query
>   performance data. The computer name is
>   optional if the counter is located on
>   the local computer.
>
> The PerfObject element specifies the
>   performance object to query. A
>   performance object can be a physical
>   component, such as processors, disks,
>   and memory, or a system object, such
>   as processes and threads. Each system
>   object is related to a functional
>   element within the computer and has a
>   set of standard counters assigned to
>   it. Each computer may have a different
>   set of performance objects and
>   counters installed on it because
>   applications can install their own
>   performance objects and counters. For
>   a list of the performance objects and
>   counters installed on your computer,
>   see the Add Counters dialog box in the
>   Performance tool on your computer.
>   These objects are also listed in the
>   PDH browse dialog box (see Browsing
>   Counters). For a list of system
>   performance objects and counters, see
>   Counters by Object.
>
> The **ParentInstance**,
>   ObjectInstance, and InstanceIndex are
>   included in the path if multiple
>   instances of the object can exist. For
>   example, processes and threads are
>   multiple instance objects because more
>   than one process or thread can run at
>   the same time. If an object can have
>   more than one instance, the counter
>   path must specify an object instance.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373193(VS.85).aspx).